# "MySQL" I need ascii value, but i got 0x____ values

Tags: mysql, char, mysql-8.0

Recently I started to learn MySQL.
In the book, this sentence was written.

```
mysql> SELECT 'abcdefg', CHAR(97);
+---------+--------------------+
| abcdefg | CHAR(97)           |
+---------+--------------------+
| abcdefg | a                  |
+---------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

but, I got something different, Hexadecimal:

```
mysql> SELECT 'abcdefg', CHAR(97);
+---------+--------------------+
| abcdefg | CHAR(97)           |
+---------+--------------------+
| abcdefg | 0x61               |
+---------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want to know the way to get ascii code value.
MySQL version is 8.

Comment: That is only an other way to represent 'a(bcdefg)' in the command line console,depending on a setting. 0x61 = 'a'

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is the setting [`--binary-as-hex`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_binary-as-hex) is enabled, which might enable as a default of `MySQL 8.0.19`

> As of MySQL 8.0.19, when mysql operates in interactive mode, this option is enabled by default

We can run the `status` or `\s` command includes this line when the option is enabled we will see

```
Binary data as: Hexadecimal
```

> To write a binary string expression so that it displays as a character string regardless of whether --binary-as-hex is enabled, use these techniques:

We can try to use the `USING` charset clause in `CHAR` function to get your expect result.

```
SELECT CHAR(97 USING utf8mb4);
```

You can try to use [`CHARSET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_charset) to check  the character set of the argument

```
SELECT 'abcdefg', CHAR(97),CHARSET(CHAR(97))
```

> | abcdefg | CHAR(97) | CHARSET(CHAR(97)) |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | abcdefg | a | binary |

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8387e1680ce3f18f9b8fd7ecc55a1860)